# matrix manipulation: set all elements to 0 except for row maximum (maxima)

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like this

```
library(matrixStats)  ## for `rowMaxs`
mymat <- matrix(c(1:10,1:10), 5,4)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    6    1    6
#[2,]    2    7    2    7
#[3,]    3    8    3    8
#[4,]    4    9    4    9
#[5,]    5   10    5   10

myvector <- rowMaxs(mymat)
```

I want all elements in each row replaced with 0 expect for maximum / maxima in that row. In this example, there are two maxima each row, so the expected result is:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    6    0    6
#[2,]    0    7    0    7
#[3,]    0    8    0    8
#[4,]    0    9    0    9
#[5,]    0   10    0   10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
## replace all elements to 0 except for row maximum; multiple maximum allowed
## recycling rule is used here, so `myvector` is replicated to be a full matrix
## i.e., equivalently: mymat[ mymat < rep.int(myvector, ncol(mymat)) ] <- 0
mymat[mymat < myvector] <- 0
```

If you want to do the reverse, i.e., setting row maximum (maxima) to 0, use

```
mymat[mymat == myvector] <- 0
```

---

You have obtained `myvector` with `matrixStats::rowMaxs`. For others who want to use R base, `max.col` is elegant:

```
## matrix indexing is used, i.e., we index matrix with a two-column matrix
myvector <- mymat[ cbind( 1:dim(mymat)[1], max.col(mymat) ) ]
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, but I am afraid it do not work if there are more than one largest number in each row. may be I have make a bad example.

Comment: That's Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I think my first solution will be along the same line to Zheyuan's post, but in a slightly different way:

```
mymat[mymat != matrix(rep(rowMaxs(mymat), ncol(mymat)),ncol=ncol(mymat))] <- 0
```

or with apply:

```
t(apply(mymat, 1, function(x) {x[x != max(x)] <- 0; x}))
```

both outputs

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    6    0    6
[2,]    0    7    0    7
[3,]    0    8    0    8
[4,]    0    9    0    9
[5,]    0   10    0   10
```